# What does the "*" in haplogroup I2A1* mean?

Tags: genetics

I have been told that the "asterisk" in the Haplogroup 12A1* means it doesn't move down stream? What exactly does that mean ***in layman's terms***?

Answer (score 2):

From the [23andMe website](https://customercare.23andme.com/hc/en-us/articles/202906900-More-about-Haplogroups):

> Sometimes there are a few lineages that don't fit into any subgroup of a haplogroup. Since there isn't a mutation that links these lineages, they don't get their own subgroup. Instead, these lineages are given the main haplogroup label plus a star (*) to indicate that they are part of the main haplogroup but don't fit into any of the known subgroups

So there are defined subgroups for I2A1 ([I2A1A and I2A1B](http://www.academia.edu/6032140/Origins_and_history_of_Haplogroup_I2_Y-DNA_)) for which more information is available, but you dont fit into any of them.

What "doesn't move down stream" means, I have no idea.